# Proposals regarding the Amazon and related tags

Tags: support, status-completed

The [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag is being misused in a similar manner to the [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) tag in that questions tagged amazon are not about the company but the services that they provide.

There are several related Amazon service tags that have consistency problems too.

[ec2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ec2) is already a synonym for [amazon-ec2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) so to make things consistent create the following synonyms

[aws](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/aws) (95)  -> [amazon-web-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) (134)

[ebs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ebs) (16) -> [amazon-ebs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ebs) (71)

[s3](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/s3) (3) -> [amazon-s3](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3) (137)

[cloudfront](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cloudfront) (14) -> [amazon-cloudfront](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudfront) (0) for consistency.

[ami](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ami) (22) -> [amazon-ami](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ami) (0) for consistency.

I've scanned all of the above and am fairly sure that the proposed synonym is used solely in reference to the Amazon service.

This one is mixed and I don't know which is the best way to go (there are windows related rds tags) - your thoughts please.

[rds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rds) (11) -> [amazon-rds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds) (6).

There are no questions tagged [elb](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/elb) however creating a synonym

[elb](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/elb) (0) -> [amazon-elb](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elb) (7) may save time in future.

There are 134 questions tagged [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) of which 96 are also tagged [amazon-ec2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2). I think we'll be fairly safe just burninate tag [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider most of these done.

[ec2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ec2) [aws](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/aws) [ebs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ebs) [s3](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/s3) [cloudfront](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cloudfront) [ami](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ami) [elb](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/elb)

<s>Like you, I'm not sure what to do with the RDS tag, because RDS is as you mentioned a very commonly used Windows tag. Especially now that Terminal Services has actually renamed itself to Remote Desktop services (RDS). I think as there's only 11, then can probably be retagged manually.</s> I have re-tagged the RDS questions. There were only 3 of them. The other 9 relate to terminal services.

On another note, you can create a lot of these synonyms on your own. Just go to the Tag Info page (click on the tag) of the *parent* tag (so, in this case, all of the [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tags) and then click "synonyms". Then all we have to do is merge them.

## Note to Stack Exchange Employees

As there are > 100 of them, can you please do a delete of [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) from all questions that now contain one of the following:

[amazon-ec2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2)
[amazon-web-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services)
[amazon-ebs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ebs)
[amazon-s3](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3)
[amazon-cloudfront](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudfront)
[amazon-ami](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ami)

The remaining [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) questions we will sort out by hand, as there should be a minimal number.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Regarding the synonyms - I would like to make them but can't as I don't have the required rep in them.

Comment: @Iain - of course, sorry, I forgot about that requirement

Comment: I have emailed the team asking then to delete the Amazon tag as per your NOTE above.

Comment: ok I destroyed the [amazon] tag

Comment: @Jeff - thanks, as always :)