# Please block the amazon tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We did some work to [remove](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1516/proposals-regarding-the-amazon-and-related-tags) the plain [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag recently but yesterday 2 questions appeared with the tag. Can the [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag be blocked please?

Comment: Can we do the same with 'vmware' too please, we got that down and now there's 144 :(

Comment: I don't think mods can blacklist tags, we can only synonym them to something else. Hopefully someone from SE sees this.

Comment: The tag blacklist is controlled by devs.

Comment: I don't believe it - another vanilla amazon tag this morning

Comment: @chopper you can't blacklist a tag that *currently exists*

Comment: Balls, so if we clear them all down can we do it then or will the fact that it *once* existed still limit us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and blacklisted [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon).

Just so you know, any blacklist entry that doesn't get a hit in 6 months is automatically deleted.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with a blacklisted tag? I was just able to ask a question and tag it amazon.

Comment: @iain it's definitely listed in the blacklist table correctly.

Comment: @JefAtwood: I can still ask a question with the amazon tag http://serverfault.com/questions/286466/what-sould-be-done-about-the-amazon-tag?noredirect=1

Comment: @iain see my response there. Patience...