# Kill it with Mundane Crystal Dagger: [fail]

Tags: discussion, tags, cleanup

The [fail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fail) tag is fail - how meta is that? And I'm posting this on a meta site. It's meta meta meta.

[fail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fail) offers no benefit. It's not likely to be searched, it does not distinguish a question's content or help people find answers or discover questions to contribute to.

[image]

---

### EDIT 1

I argue that [fail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fail) in and of itself isn't enough of a modifier to really help in the search for posts. With a name like `ServerFault` I would bet that half of all posts (at least) would be strong candidates for the [fail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fail) tag. Now *specific* failure as tags would be awesome.

- [503-error](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/503-error) It's real! Click it!
- [permission-denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/permission-denied) It's real! Click it!
- [error-5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/error-5) Not real.
- [access-denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/access-denied) It's real! Click it!

Is it something of a recurring tag? I don't think it's too terribly recurring, no. After two years we only have 13 survivors. Once a year we could sweep through a list of tags like this and kill them dead.

The nicest solution IMO would be to blacklist it. Think we can convince the right people? HAW! HAW HAW! *wipes tear* I'm so crazy sometimes.

Comment: This is getting tweeted too!

Comment: @ShaneMadden Don't hate me because I'm awesome.

Comment: I think someone needs to invent products with names/acronyms "fun", "fail", "humour" etc.

Comment: And here's me trying to search for a humorous fail, just for fun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a meta-tag, and it and its brethren should be blacklisted. They don't classify anything atomically, and by themselves they don't mean anything; they must be used with another tag. We don't like meta-tags around these parts, so they should go.

- [fail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fail)  13 questions
- [crash](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/crash) 172 questions
- [error](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/error) 66 questions
- [fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fault) 12 questions

Because of their recurring nature, they should be put on the tag blacklist like [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) is.

Comment: As per the numbers above there aren't many and if removed none would result in [tag:untagged] questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm less convinced of this one since the usage of this tag seems to less in the mode of the lolcat and more in the mode of putting the error message in the tag. By the same reasoning [error](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/error), [fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fault), and [crash](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/crash) should also be expurgated. This tag just needs a bit of pruning.

The use-case is one of a modifier on an existing tag. A meta-tag, but perhaps a useful one. A post tagged with:

[apache2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache2)[crash](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/crash)

Tells you at a glance what the main problem is.

This distinguishes it from other such now-gone metatags like:

[windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows)[windows-server-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008)

Where the meta-tag (windows) is merely an overly broad and mostly useless classifier. These tags are somewhat useful, they just need some regular maintenance to keep clean.

Comment: [tag:error] was next on my list and now that you bring it up, fault and crash *would* be on that list. It adds nothing and doesn't seem to help searches either for solutions or people looking to contribute.

Comment: If we "need" tags like `error`, `fault` and `crash` then perhaps we should also create and start using `running-properly`, `all-good`, `stable`, etc.

Comment: These are tags that naturally reoccur, so we'll either have to convince the devs to blacklist them or remember to go through every so often and purge.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers You forgot about `I-like-turtles`

Comment: Oh, and downvoted to show disagreement with an idea, but I still think you're swell.

Comment: @sysadmin1138: That's fairy easy - you just have to mail them and ask and reference the discussion. I think they have to have no questions attached too but that should be fairly easy as they just being deleted rather than retagged.

Comment: @iain When adding to the blacklist, it's best to have bigbig numbers in the answer voting. So we have a ways to go before we get there.

Comment: [vmware](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1316/can-the-vmware-tag-be-deleted) and [amazon](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1706/please-block-the-amazon-tag) which are both blacklisted had no more support that @wesleydavis's current proposal does.